# Why I can't make the imagemapster to work?

Tags: jquery, imagemapster

The following image-mapster doesn't work. Can you help me to find issue here.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script
        type="text/javascript"
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script language="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/imagemapster/1.5.4/jquery.imagemapster.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
   <section>
            <img src="https://drneetikaushik.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/chakras-7271423_960_720.jpg" alt="Chakras" id="chakra-images" class="center" usemap="#image-map">

            <map name="image-map">
                <area target="" alt="Root Chakra" title="Root Chakra" href="#" coords="90,100,10" shape="circle">
                <area target="" alt="Sacred Chakra" title="Sacred Chakra" href="#" coords="90,90,10" shape="circle">
                <area target="" alt="Solar-Plexus Chakra" title="Solar-Plexus Chakra" href="#" coords="90,65,10" shape="circle">
                <area target="" alt="Heart Chakra" title="Heart Chakra" href="#" coords="90,50,10" shape="circle">
                <area target="" alt="Throat Chakra" title="Throat Chakra" href="#" coords="90,40,10" shape="circle">
            </map>


        </section>
</body>
</html>
```

I also add the JSfiddle link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/u41horwa/) that you can run with JS and CSS file.

Comment: Right now, your fiddle is only giving me an error, that `image.mapster` is not defined. Looks like the `language="text/javascript"` is preventing the browser form loading the script correctly, so remove that first of all.

Comment: Check the network tab (F12, network) and you'll see imagemapster is not being loaded.  No idea what "imagemapster" is *supposed* to do, but removing the `language=` from the `<script>` tags means they now get loaded.  https://jsfiddle.net/hu3eqczy/1/ and comment/uncomment the `.mapster({` and it does ... *something*.

Comment: Actually I removed language = "text/javascript" and type = "text/javascript" then it worked so it was really preventing my javascript code with .mapster. Thanks